# Convert Rails Net::HTTP request to MD5 Hex Digest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-post, md5

In order to use a third-party API, I need to encode the Net::HTTP::Post request as an MD5 hex digest, which is then used as part of the signature. However, when I try to simply `Digest::MD5.hexdigest(req)`, it throws a "Cannot convert to string error", and when I explicitly `req.to_s`, it just gives the MD5 of `#<Net::HTTP::Post:0x112a0eef8>`

I'm simply:

```
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
request.body = {
  "key" => "val"
}.to_json
# later...
hexDigest = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(request)
```

which is the documented spec, I think: "[with the] JSON body containing the new information."

This is the relevant sample Java code they supply:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream requestOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
httpMethod.getEntity().writeTo(requestOutputStream);
DigestUtils.md5Hex(requestOutputStream.toByteArray()).toLowerCase();
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to call 'to_s' method explicitly, it should help:

```
hexDigest = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(request.to_s)
```

Comment: So, that runs, but I get an authentication error. I'm checking to see if it's something else, but I'm concerned because `req.to_s` results in `"#<Net::HTTP::Post:0x11273b2a8>"`

Comment: On the other hand, the `get` results in `"#<Net::HTTP::Get:0x112732d88>"` and that still works sooo

Comment: Nope - It runs on "GET" because I don't `to_s` the GET. Your answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent ruby code for those lines is:

```
OpenSSL::Digest::MD5.hexdigest(request.body)
```

`httpMethod.getEntity()` will return the json defined as the request body.

`requestOutputStream.toByteArray()` will return the array of bytes corresponding to the request body.